# Need clarification on a very very VERY simple python program

Tags: python

I was just wondering why in the following function,

```
def test(num): 
  if num > 0:
    return test(num - 1)
  else: 
    return 0
```

any value I enter is returned as 0.

Comment: are you familiar with recursion?

Comment: Can you explain why you thought it would return something other than 0?

Comment: you *probably* want `num-1` instead of `test(num-1)`

Comment: Given what the function says, what would you expect `test(1)` to return?

Answer (score 3):

The function is recursive - it calls itself as long as the parameter is positive.
So whenever you send in any positive parameter it will call itself with a value
one smaller, until the value gets to zero - in which case it just returns zero.
If you try to call it with a negative number the condition will cause it to return immediately a zero value.

Comment: Thank you! So just to clarify, if i were to simply do                                                                    "return test(num - 1) + num"     and pass 5 for example, the function would execute 5 -1 + 5? or since 5 - 1 is executed first, would num be equal to 4? Sorry i am new to programming as a whole and am still learning some basics.EDIT: nevermind it just clicked lolol thank you guys

Answer (score 1):

I have added numbering for each line so that I can refer the lines in the example

```
1 def test(num): 
2  if num > 0:
3    return test(num - 1)
4  else: 
5    return 0
```

Let's take an Example

```
a = 2
test(2)
```

if will reach "line number 2" where  2(current num) > 0
so at "line number 3":
if will return a new function call to test(2-1)

so return of test(2) -> test(1)

now for test(1)

it will again reach "line number 2" where 1(current num) > 0
so again at "line number 3":
ii will again return a new function call to test(1-1) -> test(0)

now for test(0)
it will again reach "line number 2" where 0(current num) > 0 will be false
so now it will go inside else at "line number 5":
from where it returns 0 which is an integer  and not a recursive function call

Answer (score 0):

def test(num):
if num > 0:
return (num - 1)
else:
return 0
print test(8)

In the line with return you have called name of the function. If you do this it will return 7. Because you were calling the function within the definition of the function that caused the problem. Call the function after you have specified the entire function.

Comment: The code i posted was not written by me, i simply have to explain why the function is returning the values that it does for one of my classes.